# Check Kuhn-Tucker conditions

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

How to check if $(0,1)$ point is the solution of this optimization problem using Kuhn-Tucker Theorem.

Find the min of $e^{x_1-x_2}-x_1-x_2$ where $x_1+x_2\le1,\  x_1\ge 0,\  x_2\ge0$

I am thinking about inverting last two conditions to $\le$ and using Lagrange multiplier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}&=e^{x-y}-x-y-\lambda_1(1-x-y)-\lambda_2(x)-\lambda _3(y)\\
\mathcal{L'}&=\binom{e^{x-y}-1}{-e^{x-y}-1} -\lambda_1\binom{-1}{-1}-\lambda_2\binom{1}{0}-\lambda _3\binom{0}{1}\\
\end{align}
So you want to satisfy:
\begin{align}
0=\mathcal{L'}&=\binom{e^{x-y}-1}{-e^{x-y}-1} -\lambda_1\binom{-1}{-1}-\lambda_2\binom{1}{0}-\lambda _3\binom{0}{1}\\
x+y&\leq1\\
x&\geq0\\
y&\geq0\\
\lambda_i&\geq0\\
\lambda_1(x+y-1)&=0\\
\lambda_2(x)&=0\\
\lambda_3(y)&=0
\end{align}
At $(0,1)$,

Feasibility Checks Out

\begin{align}
\lambda_3&=0\qquad\text{ From Complimentarity Equation}\\
\lambda_1&=1.36\qquad\text{ From Optimality Equation}\\
\lambda_2&=0.73\qquad\text{ From Optimality Equation}\\
\end{align}

Everything Checks Out.

It *is* a KKT point.

Similarly, you can check the Second Order Necessary Conditions.

Note : It is Optimal.